# How to solve System.OutofMemoryException in linq using C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list. First list consist 70000 row and second list consist 20000 row. After join two list 'System.OutofMemoryException' error occour.

Here my code:

```
var resultx12 = (from a in resultx
                 join b in resultx1
                 on new { stdtab = a.sectionStd.Trim(), stdli = a.liStd.Trim() }
                 equals new { stdtab = b.sectionStd.Trim(), stdli = b.liStd.Trim() }
                 into tempBrokerBogeyMapped
                 from x in tempBrokerBogeyMapped.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 .Skip(totalFetched)
                 .Take(1000)
                 select new LiReportCompareContainer
                 {
                     Origin = Origin,
                     Broker = data.Broker,
                     FormulaStd = a.FormulaStd,
                     Formula = x == null ? "" : String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Formula) ? "" : x.Formula.Trim(),
                     Group = a.Group,
                     liBroker = a.liBroker,
                     Link = a.Link,
                     liStd = a.liStd,
                     Period1 = a.Period1,
                     Period1Value = a.Period1Value,
                     Period2 = a.Period2,
                     Period2Value = a.Period2Value,
                     Period3 = a.Period3,
                     Period3Value = a.Period3Value,
                     sectionBroker = a.sectionBroker,
                     sectionStd = a.sectionStd,
                     Unit = a.Unit,
                 }).ToList();
```

System.OutofMemoryException error showing.

Comment: with `.Take(1000)` there shouldn't be a `OutofMemoryException `

Comment: try to profile RAM usage, it`s hard to tell what is causing this without actual running app...

Comment: @fubo: `.Skip(totalFetched)` can produce a lot of objects.

Comment: @apocalypse `.Skip(totalFetched)` is still `IEnumerable` which isn't materialized

Comment: How many bytes are free in your ram memory?

Comment: @fubo: but if you have `.Skip(1000000).Take(1).ToList();` you still need to enumerate 1000000 items, and each item can produce new objects. Garbage collector will not clean it in time.

Comment: @FaridImranov: Total Ram: 8073 MB.. Free: 1033 MB

Comment: @apocalypse: It generates only 1 new object when `.ToList()` method called. Iteration goes through the existing list items.

Comment: @Soumyadeep.R, if there is no any big objects in your list, then it must not be throw `OutOfMemoryException`. 1033 MB is big enough memory for 1000 items. How many bytes are there for per item, can you calculate this?

Comment: @FaridImranov: but it does not magically skips code execution. In this case for example it needs to create many anonymous objects. It's hard to tell whats going on here without more code details.

Comment: What type do resultx and resultx1 have exactly? You mentioned lists, but its not clear whether you meant List<T> or rather some table of data. If they are IEnumerable results from another linq querry, the evaluation could cause the OutOfMemory from there.